# Remove funny characters

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I have the below line

`development which in turn â€¢ Activates the brain â€¢ Strengthens the brain connections â€¢`

What does  `â€¢` mean and how can i rectify it using php. Is it something to do with UTF-8 encoding or someother encoding?

Comment: Have you tried [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) on it? Also make sure `<meta charset='utf-8'>` within html.

Comment: It would be better to _prevent_ this kind of error rather than _fix_ it.

Comment: Where is the line coming from?

Comment: Looks like a delimiter, you could also try [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on `â€¢`.

Comment: @DaveChen: have tried it but not working

Comment: maybe iconv() will help? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php
also try debugging the place where it occurs...(var_dump or print_r, maybe try error_reporting(E_ALL))

Comment: Where are you getting this string from? I'd recommend [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on it too.

Comment: The fix would be: guess the current encoding; turn into a byte stream (PHP string) using that encoding; turn into a character stream using the correct encoding (UTF-8?) (by echoing it into a correctly marked up document)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I agree but unfortunately whoever has coded it has made the blunder and the data is already inserted into the database table.

Comment: Check the php.ini file and tell me which value does it have on this parameter: default_charset. It is recommended to set it to "utf-8". Also check the encoding in which your browser is recognizing your page

Comment: @Juhana: Unfortunately from the database.

Comment: Then you need to find the encoding he used. I can shoot at random (for the most common code pages), but I can never be sure

Answer (score 6):

I would guess you have data encoded in UTF-8 (where  the byte sequence `0xe2 0xa4 0xa2` (which could represent `â€¢` in ISO-8859-15 and possibly other encodings) corresponds to Unicode Character ['NORTH EAST AND SOUTH WEST ARROW' (U+2922)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2922/index.htm), `⤢`

Make sure you use a consistent encoding in the database, and make sure you output method uses the same encoding.

*Edit*: 
If a [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) terminal outputs `â€¢`, it got the byte sequence `0xe2 0x80 0xa2`. That corresponds to Unicode Character ['BULLET' (U+2022)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm). This seems to be a more likely encoding mixup.

Comment: Since it looks like it's meant to be a bullet point, I guess your guess about ISO-8859-15 is incorrect (but it still demonstrates a point - you can't ask a computer to recover the string automatically)

Comment: Is there any other code page that contains all of `â€¢` at different locations?

Comment: +1; the fact that the generated byte stream is valid UTF-8 is sufficient for me :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Added Windows-1252 interpretation, which seems more likely.

Comment: Yeah, it seems much more likely :-) The output is more expected and the input encoding is more common :-) I'm still surprised that ISO-8859-15 produces a valid UTF-8

Comment: Is it advisable to use mb_detect_encoding(); to find the character encoding?

Comment: @John Encodings cannot, by definition, be "detected" reliably. Especially any single-byte encoding will look like any other single byte encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
$char = utf8_decode('development which in turn Ã¢â�¬Â¢ Activates the brain Ã¢â�¬Â¢ Strengthens the brain connections Ã¢â�¬Â¢');
$r = utf8_decode('Ã¢â�¬Â¢');
echo $upd = str_replace($r, '', $char);
```

try Online: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ its working for me

Comment: I don't want to replace those special character. I want them to be displayed as how they originally displayed before turning into funny characters.